# Angular2 Handling multiple views in one component

Tags: angular, components, angular2-template

I am developing one web application. I have one account folder say component.
I want to create account related stuff inside this like login,registration, forgotpassword etc.

Is it better approach in angular2 to put everything like this inside one component.
Also is it possible in angular2 to use like this way.

Answer (score 0):

No Angular is made to force you to split your code in different component .. and possibly having them in different routing (I mean not all included in one father layout) .. because if you have routing you can load them `lazy` .. and don't have a heavy bootstrap ...

Comment: If it help you rate it if you want ... thnx !! Happy if it helped you !!